# Ruby on Rails using a POST method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow this guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails-bang
and in section 5.7 it says to add this line.

post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show

What does this do, and where should I put it?  I tried putting it in the "create" method that follows this form:

http://dixonc3-72812.use1.nitrousbox.com/posts/new

I also tried putting it in the "view" because I figured it was accepting the "POST" method.  How do I proceed?   New to Ruby on Rails and trying to figure out the kinks.

Comment: learn about routes http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to follow this guide:
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails-bang
>   and in section 5.7 it says to add this line.
>
> post GET /posts/:id(.:format) posts#show

Section 5.7 doesn't tell you that.  What it tells you is the following is output of `rake routes` for the `show` action:

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
```

The output is presented in a tabular format where the four columns are (from left to right): `Prefix, Verb, URI Pattern, Controller#Action`.

In order to get this, you need to declare `posts` as a resource in `config/routes.rb` as:

```
resources :posts, only: [:show]
```

Now if you run `rake routes` in your terminal, you will see the line included from the guide.

The above line in `config/routes.rb` defines a route for the `show` action.  You can remove `only: [ :show ]` option to have routes defined for all standard RESTful actions, i.e. in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts
```

Comment: Ok, In my config/routes.rb I have resources :posts already.   Very helpful answer though!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the routes for show action of posts controller, for create action you find something like

```
posts#create
```

Comment: So something like?  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
  end